# Will an MX record "follow" a CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, mx-record

I have a situation I'm trying to work through that I'm not entirely sure how to solve.

Here's the situation:

I have a domain, let's say `sub.otherdomain.com`, that I want to set up e-mail addresses on, and additionally set up an A record on. I don't own this domain, but the owners of the domain have set up a `CNAME` record to point to one of my domains (let's say `customer.mydomain.com`)

My understanding is that setting up a `CNAME` record will cause all record lookups for `sub.otherdomain.com` to use the records defined on `customer.mydomain.com`. This seems to work fine for the `A` record I have set up, but the `MX` records don't seem to be passing through the `CNAME` correctly.

In summary, the following records exist:

### sub.otherdomain.com

```
CNAME  customer.mydomain.com
```

### customer.mydomain.com

```
A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
MX (mx details)
```

My assumption is that e-mails sent to xxx@sub.otherdomain.com would use the `MX` records from `customer.mydomain.com`. Is this not the case?

Comment: I think your initial assumption is correct - the mail server should follow the CNAME pointer and retrieve the records for customer.mydomain.com. What happens when you dig -t MX sub.otherdomain.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt

> The domain names that a Sender-SMTP sends in MAIL and RCPT
>            commands MUST have been  "canonicalized," i.e., they must be
>            fully-qualified principal names or domain literals, not
>            nicknames or domain abbreviations.  A canonicalized name either
>            identifies a host directly or is an MX name; it cannot be a CNAME.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, it's impossible to set up MX records on a domain that has CNAMEs defined on it, even if the MX records are defined "further down the chain"?

Comment: RFC 5321 disagrees with this. RFC 1123 references RFC 821 for SMTP, which is long obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this should work. From [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321):

> Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted when
> domain names are used in SMTP.  In other words, names that can be resolved to
> MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed in Section 5) are
> permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be resolved, in turn, to MX or
> address RRs.

and:

> The lookup first attempts to locate an MX record associated with the name.
> If a CNAME record is found, the resulting name is processed as if it were the
> initial name.